# how to randomly move sprites in andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I want to know the method for randomly moving the sprites smoothly in andengine?
I want to have balls in my game moving continously in random directions like "Brownian Movement".

I have searched alot and have tried to get that by using MoveModifier ,but unfortunately that didn't work....

Answer (score 4):

Check the moving ball example, you only make a Class extends Sprite or AnimatedSprite, later you only set random values in X and Y speed:

```
private static class Ball extends AnimatedSprite {
            private final PhysicsHandler mPhysicsHandler;
                    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
                    private float RandomX;
                    private float RandomY;
                    private int CAMERA_WIDTH=720;
                    private int CAMERA_HEIGHT=480; 
            public Ball(final float pX, final float pY, final TiledTextureRegion pTextureRegion, final VertexBufferObjectManager pVertexBufferObjectManager) {
                super(pX, pY, pTextureRegion, pVertexBufferObjectManager);
                this.mPhysicsHandler = new PhysicsHandler(this);
                this.registerUpdateHandler(this.mPhysicsHandler);
                            RandomX =randomGenerator.nextInt(3);
                            RandomY =randomGenerator.nextInt(3);
                            RandomX=RandomX*100;  
                            RandomY=RandomY*100;
                this.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocity(RandomX, RandomY);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onManagedUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) {
                if(this.mX < 0) {
                    this.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityX(RandomX);
                } else if(this.mX + this.getWidth() > CAMERA_WIDTH) {
                    this.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityX(-RandomX);
                }

                if(this.mY < 0) {
                    this.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityY(RandomY);
                } else if(this.mY + this.getHeight() > CAMERA_HEIGHT) {
                    this.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityY(-RandomY);
                }

                super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You either use box2d like what "Vinicius DSL" said or you could move the balls manually by overriding onUpdate [or onManagedUpdated] and changing their x and y locations from there